# c# Excel losing formulae after save

Tags: c#, excel

Excel formula get lost after saving, were replaced by last calculation result.

**Question: Is there a special save option in order to keep formulas ?**

```
rangeTarget = workSheetTeam.get_Range(workSheetTeam.Cells[40, BG], workSheetTeam.Cells[40, BG]);
rangeTarget.Formula = "=MAX(BF8:BF25)";
```

Comment: Perhaps if you showed the code that *does* the save, it might be useful. (Current guess - you're not saving as an Excel file, but as a CSV or another format where a formula and its value cannot both be saved for a cell, so it saves the value)

Comment: it's quite straight forward: workBook1.SaveAs(newFile);

Comment: If you're not specifying a file format to [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx), are you working with an existing workbook (which will retain the same format) or a new workbook (which will save as Excel format)?

Comment: when do you add the formula data? If you then save the s/s manually yourself are formulas still removed?

Comment: the formular where preexisting in the excel sheet. I tried to rewrite them (see above) but in vain. I saved the XLS as XLS manualy and it worked well - all formular are present. I killed the Excel process after a Save() command in order to avoid a SaveAs and a Close(), did NOT work.

Comment: what is the extension of newFile?